# Number of ways to construct a Regular graph

Tags: graph, graph-theory, combinatorics

For a regular graph (each vertex has same degree k), a part of graph upto level l is given, how to compute the total number of ways in which the graph can be completed given that m edges and n vertices are yet to be added to the preconstructed graph ?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming problem, it seems to be about Computer Science. There's another site for that you know: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It seems there is no closed form answer to this. See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77730/how-many-p-regular-graphs-with-n-vertices-are-there) and [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22089/enumeration-of-regular-graphs/22109#22109)